# How to change the language of Steam games?

Tags: steam

Some of the Steam games in my region have single language support only, next to them it is written:

> Notice: Purchases made in this region will only receive the Russian
>   language.

mostly games from Ubisoft have that restrictions. how can I change the language of the game for example to English, is it possible?

I've seen videos showing that if we delete localization files in the game directory it will use English or something like that but I'm not sure.

Comment: I also see this note for my language (German) where it is code for "This version is the censored one, because it's against the law to sell the uncensored version to people in your country". But I am not sure if this also applies to Russia.

Comment: @Philipp I think that is only for Germany, some games like Dying Light had that kind of limitations in Germany, I wonder why

Comment: The videogame censorship system in Germany is rather complex with 3 competing processes (USK, BPjM, court-mandated confiscation) with each one having different powers. This is an interesting topic, but off-topic for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the game itself doesn't allow you to change the language and in Steam game properties (right-click the game, select `Properties`) under `Language` tab you do not have any other languages than Russian, then I believe it's not possible officially.

That said, you might be able to find some language packs on the Internet, but keep in mind this might break your game if the files are for different version of the game etc.

The tip with removing localization files might work, but I suppose it differs game to game and could also have some side-effects.

Comment: To fix your answer, it is now "Language" tab not localization. and I'm sure when Steam store says a game only supports a specific language then there is most likely no other languages available in the languages tab.

Comment: @Conspiria thanks, updated my answer with proper name of the tab